# FB Audience Network in Cordova apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

We are currently building Cordova/Ionic hybrid mobile app and we would like to integrate Audience Network. App is written in HTML/CSS/JavaScript and for the Audience Network there is only Native SDK available. Is there a Cordova plugin on someone's roadmap? Or is there a way how to integrate Native SDK without plugin? I'm even considering to create a Cordova plugin myself, but I have barely minimal experiences with Java and Objective-C/Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Xie just coded one a few days ago:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads

Answer (score 0):

The [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) team created [ngCordova](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova) which is providing the [Facebook AudienceNetwork Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/) contributed by [floatinghotpot](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads).

**Usage**:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($cordovaFacebookAds) {
    $cordovaFacebookAds.showBanner();
});
```